# Ajax success returning object Object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have reviewed the other topics, but so far i have not found any solutions. I know i am doing something wrong..

here is my php:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode((object)array(
    "content" =>
        $emailAddress
));
```

and my ajax success part:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                url: "getemailaddress.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
                dataType:"json", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                data:myData, //Form variables
                success:function(response){
                    $("#emailtoinvite").val($(response.content))
                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    //display error message here
                }
            });
```

my input box gets the following value:

```
[object Object]
```

do you have any suggestion how to solve the problem? thanks!

Comment: you have problem by $ in `$(response.content)` remove $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what exactly you ask to do:

```
$(response.content)
```

is an expression that returns an instance of jquery object that performed lookup over a CSS selector specified in `response.content` variable.

What you actually need is:

```
$("#emailtoinvite").val(response.content)
                       ^--- a plain value, not a `$` function call
```

Comment: god, how could i be that unperceptive...
thank you, that solved the problem!